# Windows CLI: Find file with dir /s/b in a specific folder

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, dir

I'm trying to locate a file and get the whole path of it. For this I wanted to execute the command:

```
dir "install.log" /s/b
```

The problem is, the command only searches inside the current directory and subfolders, but I want to look through the whole drive. Is there any way to specify the search path, like it is done in Linux with `find` (`find /path -name "file"`)

So you may ask, why do I not simply change directory with `cd`? I connect remotely via ssh to a Windows machine were copssh is running. The command is always executed in the home directory of copssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dir /s /b \install.log
```

Just instruct dir command to start from root of current drive, or add drive if needed

```
dir /s /b x:\install.log
```